# svn server export timing out

Tags: svn

for some reason svn export commands are failing:  Small repo checkout is failing... Maybe 100Mb of files.

```
[Mon Jan 09 19:09:19 2012] [error] [client 10.250.14.61] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
[Mon Jan 09 19:09:19 2012] [error] [client 10.250.14.61] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #103]
[Mon Jan 09 19:09:19 2012] [error] [client 10.250.14.61] Error writing base64 data: Software caused connection abort  [500, #103]

svn: REPORT of '/svnreponame/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: Connection reset by peer (https://svn.blah.com)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The server (or a device between you and the server) is killing the connection.  The culprit may be a setting on the server, or a firewall in front of the server.  Do you control the server?  Can you provide information on how it's configured?

Comment: Thanks Shane...  will check the load balancers/firewalls